# how to design database table record in monthly for Evaluate System

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a system which is staff can submit their evaluate marks of the maintenance work of golf course in monthly. The evaluation in each hole.Marks will insert in 1 to 5 marks in each hole.

The column are the category of job, job of work, frequency,hole1,hole2, hole3, hole4.

Moreover, the category of job, job of work, frequency can insert new and can be updated by user if needed.

After evaluating marks need to calculate each hole job have been done in percentage. I decide total all the marks in divide how many jobs have.

However, my issue is with the DB Design, I don't know how to design it to make it work.

So far my Idea is:

(No. varchar(5), JobCategory varchar(15), JobLocation Varchar(15), Hole1 int, Hole2 int, Hole3 int, Hole4 int, Hole5 int, Marks int)

but how do I record in monthly?

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Edit tile to be specific to your particular Question’s issues.